# Limiting EFS access on AWS Lambda for a user

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, user-management, amazon-efs

## Background

I have an AWS Lambda (of Image type) configured through a `Dockerfile`. The Lambda function should execute an arbitrary python code (the code is sent from a user, and therefore can be malicious and should be restricted).

There is important information stored in the [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) (mounted on `/mnt/efs`) which should be accessible from the Lambda, but not from the user's code. The EFS access point is configured as:

```yaml
  AccessPointResource:
    Type: 'AWS::EFS::AccessPoint'
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref FileSystemResource
      PosixUser:
        Uid: '1000'
        Gid: '1000'
      RootDirectory:
        CreationInfo:
          OwnerGid: '1000'
          OwnerUid: '1000'
          Permissions: '0777'
        Path: '/mnt/efs'
```

#### Initial idea that did not work

- Restrict `AccessPointResource` to allow reads for only a specific group
- Include the main lambda user in the group
- Create a Linux user that is not in the group
- When running the submitted code, run under the newly created user's credentials

#### The reasons why it didn't work:

- When creating a user in the Dockerfile, the user disappears when deploying the image

  - Tried creating the user with both `RUN /usr/sbin/useradd -ms /bin/bash coderunner` and in the `entrypoint.sh`
  - Tried creating the user inside the lambda (in the python code) - Permission denied (the main user of the lambda does not have permissions to access `/usr/sbin/useradd`)
- When specifying the user for Popen following the [guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), all the commands fail with permission denied - for any user even (with the current one).

#### Additional information

- AWS lambda seems to reset all the users and their permissions when the docker image is deployed to match the Lambda restrictions
- It creates ~150 other users to manage the access within the Lambda image
- When printing `os.getuid(), getpass.getuser(), os.getgroups()` we get `993 sbx_user1051 []`
- When printing `cat /etc/passwd` we get ~150 users and none of them is the user that we created (coderunner)

## The main question

Is there a way of permitting the main AWS Lambda code to access the EFS on `/mnt/efs` but restricting the access for a code launched through a python subprocess?